# How to display JSON data on view page

Tags: c#, html, json, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project where I have a JSON file and am trying to pass that data through MVC to be displayed on a web page. As part of the JSON file, I have some data that I am trying to pass to my view, it looks like:

```
"htmlContent": "<p>It was over two decades ago that Bill Gates declared&nbsp;‘Content is King’&nbsp;and the&nbsp;consensus&nbsp;still stands today&nbsp;with it&nbsp;arguably&nbsp;being&nbsp;the most important part of designing a website.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>Content is essentially your&nbsp;UX.&nbsp;It&nbsp;encompasses&nbsp;the images, words, videos&nbsp;and&nbsp;data&nbsp;featured across your website.&nbsp;If the main purpose of your site is to share valuable and relevant content to engage your audience, then you should be&nbsp;considering your content&nbsp;long&nbsp;before embarking on&nbsp;a web project.&nbsp;All too often,&nbsp;businesses miss the opportunity to create impressive UX designs, instead waiting&nbsp;until the later stages of the project to sign off content which inevitably creates&nbsp;new challenges to overcome.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p>Having a research strategy in place that supports&nbsp;a content-first design approach should be at the top of your agenda.&nbsp;When&nbsp;businesses&nbsp;choose to design content-first,&nbsp;they&nbsp;are&nbsp;putting&nbsp;their&nbsp;valuable&nbsp;resources&nbsp;centre&nbsp;stage,&nbsp;conveying their brand&nbsp;through&nbsp;effective&nbsp;and&nbsp;engaging UX design.&nbsp;Throughout this blog, we will&nbsp;share&nbsp;our tips on how&nbsp;you can&nbsp;develop a content-first design approach.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h2><strong>How to develop a content-first design approach&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;</h2>\r\n<p>Content can no longer be an after-thought,&nbsp;but&nbsp;there’s no denying that&nbsp;generating content can be a tricky. To get you thinking along the right lines&nbsp;and help put pen to paper, follow our top tips:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h3><strong>Ask lots of questions</strong>&nbsp;</h3>\r\n<p>Generating content that successfully satisfies what your customers want to know requires a lot of research. Get into the habit of asking open-ended questions that answer the Who, What, Where, When, Why and How. Using this approach will allow you to delve deep and gain an understanding of what your website should&nbsp;include&nbsp;to&nbsp;build a considered site map.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h3><strong>Consider your Information Architecture&nbsp;(IA)</strong>&nbsp;</h3>\r\n<p>How your&nbsp;content is organised and divided across the website is a crucial aspect of UX design.&nbsp;Without effective sorting, most users would be completely lost when navigating&nbsp;a&nbsp;site&nbsp;and there’s no point having&nbsp;memorable features if they can’t be found!&nbsp;Use card sorting exercises, tree tests, user journey mapping&nbsp;and user flow diagrams to&nbsp;form&nbsp;an understanding of how&nbsp;best&nbsp;to display your content in a logical and accessible way.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h3><strong>Conduct&nbsp;qualitative and&nbsp;quantitative&nbsp;research</strong>&nbsp;</h3>\r\n<p>Although Google Analytics is extremely useful, it doesn’t hold all the answers.&nbsp;Google&nbsp;Analytics is great at telling you&nbsp;<em>what</em>&nbsp;your users are doing, but it doesn’t give you&nbsp;the&nbsp;insight into&nbsp;<em>why</em>&nbsp;they’re doing it. Qualitative one-to-one user interviews is an effective method of really getting to grips with&nbsp;your user needs&nbsp;to&nbsp;understand&nbsp;why they do what they do.&nbsp;User&nbsp;testing also falls into this category.&nbsp;Seeing a user navigate through your website on a mobile phone&nbsp;in day to day life&nbsp;can give you great insight&nbsp;for&nbsp;UX design&nbsp;in terms of&nbsp;context and situation.&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h3><strong>Align your content strategy with long-term business goals</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>\r\n<p>Before beginning your web project,&nbsp;it’s important to understand the goals of the project and the pain points you are trying to solve.&nbsp;Include all the necessary stakeholders within this&nbsp;research&nbsp;to gain a comprehensive understanding of these insights&nbsp;before embarking on your web design project.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<h3><strong>Content first, design second</strong>&nbsp;</h3>\r\n<p>Avoid designing&nbsp;content boxes across your website and trying to squeeze the content into these boxes.&nbsp;When designing a new website, it may seem&nbsp;counter&nbsp;intuitive&nbsp;to begin with a page of words&nbsp;rather than a&nbsp;design mock-up. But, it’s important to remember that Lorem Ipsum isn’t going to help anyone either.&nbsp;Begin with the content your users&nbsp;need&nbsp;and then design out from&nbsp;there.&nbsp;Capturing&nbsp;the content&nbsp;and its structure can be done in many ways;&nbsp;we like to build content models&nbsp;based on IA site maps and qualitative user testing such as card sorting&nbsp;and user journey mapping.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p>By&nbsp;using a content-first&nbsp;design&nbsp;approach, you can&nbsp;understand what content needs to fit&nbsp;into your website&nbsp;design.&nbsp;Analysing your website’s content needs in the early stages or,&nbsp;even better, prior to the project beginning,&nbsp;can effectively&nbsp;inform and shape all touch points ultimately generating an optimised&nbsp;result&nbsp;with reduced time delays and constraints&nbsp;along the way. If you&nbsp;have a web project in mind and need help&nbsp;on how to get started,&nbsp;<a href=\"https://www.netconstruct.co.uk/contact/\">get in touch</a>&nbsp;with the team today.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>",
```

In the view I am then accessing this JSON data through a foreach loop and can access it like so

```
@jsondata.htmlContent
```

This then gets said 'htmlcontent' from the JSON file, when I open the html web page the 'htmlcontext' is not working as I would expect it to, the '<p.>' tag does not display as a paragraph on the web page, instead the content on the web page is exactly the same as the JSON string.

How would I go about doing this and displaying the data in the tags?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(jsondata.htmlcontent)` - be careful though, there's a reason it's escaped by default. If there's a script tag in the json it will be embedded and run

Comment: That's great thank you, that worked perfectly! This is just a test project that I have created myself but for learning purposes, how would you catch any script tags in the content?